# How to share a group of python module using Conda

Tags: python, share, package, conda, multi-user

I have 30 users that have Anaconda installed. What is the best way to create share directories that contain a group of packages (with their dependenccies) ? Let say that for some project we need to have a common list of packages on top of the standard Anaconda version. What is the best way to achieve that ?

- `conda list --export > package-list.txt`
  and reinstall packages from an export file:
  `conda create -n myenv --file package-list.txt`
  but each user will need to install these packages on their PC
  and it could be an issue to do that on a server for example
- use channel and put all our packages but I didn't find an automatic way to do that and to put a list of python packages with their dependencies.
- I am not sure that conda env will help since I want the installation to be done on a specific directory (on a share disk)

Is there a better option ? I never did that before so maybe I am not looking in the right direction. The other constraint is that we are using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is probably the standard/best option. Shouldn't be a problem doing this on a server as long as you have access to the Internet. If you want it in a specific directory, you can specify this with the `--path` parameter in your call to `conda create`.

Comment: Thanks, this look like a good idea but `conda create -n myenv --file packages-list.txt -p "C:\Test"` doesn't work since with `conda create` options `-n` and `-p` ( --path doesn't exist in conda 4.2.12) cannot be used together. I get the following message: "conda-script.py create: error: argument -p/--prefix: not allowed with argument -n/--name"

Comment: `conda create  --file packages-list.txt -p "Test"`` put the packages in the Test dicrectory. I Need to do more tests now. Thanks